# How do I get a button to appear alongside the list items?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a basic to-do list app with Javascript.  I'm able to input list elements, but I'm having trouble making the "delete" button alongside my list elements, as well as getting that button to delete the item within the list.

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)

  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.innerHTML = "X";
  remove.addEventListener('click', () => this.remove(todoInput));

}
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <label>Task Name: </label>
  <input id="todoInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
</form>
<ol id="todoList">
</ol>
```

Comment: You have problem in html/css or js for this?

Comment: append it to the list item

Answer (score 1):

You're not append the newly created `remove` button element to the DOM at all. If you should appended as a child of `newItem` before you append `newItem` to the DOM.

Also, if you want the remove button to delete an entry, it is as simply as invoking `newItem.remove()` in its callback. Since the variable is function scoped each remove button will "remember" which `<li>` element it should be removing. There is no need to traverse the parent DOM tree to find out which node to delete:

```js
function todoList() {
  const item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value;
  const text = document.createTextNode(item);
  const newItem = document.createElement("li");
  newItem.appendChild(text);
  
  // Create the button
  const remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.innerHTML = "X";
  remove.addEventListener('click', () => newItem.remove());
  
  // Make sure you also append it to the new `<li>` element!
  newItem.appendChild(remove);
  
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)
}
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <label>Task Name: </label>
  <input id="todoInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
</form>
<ol id="todoList">
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added to things

1- changed the element to input then set its type to button

2- appended the button to the child list.

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  
  
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem);

  var remove = document.createElement('input');//Element is input 
  remove.type="button"; // type is button or whaterver you want
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.innerHTML = "X";
  remove.addEventListener('click', () => this.remove(todoInput));
  newItem.append(remove);

}
```

```css
.remove{
  margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>TaskApp</h1>
    <h2>Version 0.1</h2>

    <form id="todoForm">
      <label>Task Name: </label>
      <input id="todoInput">
      <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <ol id="todoList">
    </ol>

    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made two main adjustments to your code. First I added the remove-button to the newly created `li` and second I rewrote its click-handler to remove its parent-element:

```js
function todoList() {
  var item = document.getElementById("todoInput").value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement("li")
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  remove.innerHTML = "X";
  remove.addEventListener('click', ({target}) => target.parentElement.remove());
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  newItem.appendChild(remove)
  document.getElementById("todoList").appendChild(newItem)  

}
```

```html
<form id="todoForm">
  <label>Task Name: </label>
  <input id="todoInput">
  <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
</form>
<ol id="todoList">
</ol>
```